# How to calculate the mean training score using GridSearchCV in Scikit-Learns

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation

I would like to plot the  mean validation vs mean training score for  Linear Support Vector machine in a similar fashion as done here: http://youtu.be/9qg9__n4X2A?t=20m33s

However when running similar code the parameter `compute_training_scores` does not seem to exist. 
Also this parameter is not documented [1]. I checked the current master branch on Github and it does not seem to be committed yet.

I am using Scikit-learn 0.14.1

I am a bit confused here. Is there branch or tag that I need in order to get the same functionality or is there a alternative way to calculate this?

The code in question:

```
param_grid = {'C': 10. ** np.arange(-3, 4)}
grid_search = GridSearchCV(svm, param_grid=param_grid, cv=3, verbose=3, compute_training_score=True)
grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train);

plt.plot([c.mean_validation_score for c in grid_search.cv_scores_], label="validation error")
plt.plot([c.mean_training_score for c in grid_search.cv_scores_], label="training error")
plt.xticks(np.arange(6), param_grid['C']); plt.xlabel("C"); plt.ylabel("Accuracy");plt.legend(loc='best');
```

If I run the same code without the offending parameter I get:

```
AttributeError: '_CVScoreTuple' object has no attribute 'mean_training_score'
```

[1] http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html

Comment: Can you add your reference [1]?

Comment: Shot in the dark: Maybe you could extract the data from "``cv_validation_scores``, the list of scores for each fold"

Comment: I cannot find the keyword `compute_training_scores` anywhere in the repo either. I cannot watch the tutorial right now, but this is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

`mean_validation_score` <del>and `mean_training_score`</del> will be available in the next scikit-learn release, 0.15. You need to install from GitHub to get it.

Comment: I can only find `mean_validation_score`. Can you point me to `mean_training_score`?

Comment: Actually the branch that has it never got merged :-/

Comment: Thanks ! where I can get that branch? and will it be merged? I find this really useful to generate such graphs.